# Error at ETL " Get Files via FTPS " on Pentaho : FTP IO exception return value 530

Tags: ftp, pentaho

I'm using " Get Files via FTPS " on Pentaho Data Integration and after insert IP address, user and password, it's getting " ftp IO exception return value 530 description error connection "
Can someone say if is a problem with the connection or I'm missing something at this ETL.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

in ftps sername/ ip address if you only specify www.websitename.com then 530 error will come, so along with this you have to specify port number as well...

```
www.websitename.com:port-number
```

this thing will solve your problem.